# Netty: how to share Object bewteen Channel

Tags: java, netty

first of all, thank you to get on this question.

I want to use Netty to implement a function like collect infomation from other website and show it, so Server ChannelHandler implements like this:

```
public class ProxyRedirectHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {

    private final Logger logger = getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest msg) throws Exception {
        logger.info("proxy request start");

        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();

        bootstrap.group(ctx.channel().eventLoop())
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                // this handler include collect strategy and get response
                .handler(new HttpClientHandler())
                .connect(new InetSocketAddress("www.baidu.com", 443));

        // show response
        ctx.writeAndFlush(response)
                .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
}
```

core question confuse me is how can I get response from HttpClientHandler in method channelRead0,

Comment: It seems that this is a kind of weird implementation.  Are you going to wait for the response synchronously in your  ```channelRead``` method and then respond?

Comment: @zysaaa i don` t want to use synchronosly way, this is the reason why i use netty to implement. i want to new a bootstrap in `channelRead0` as a client and visit website that i want to collect, and multiplex EventLoopGroup that i use in ServerBootstrap. i think this way can take high concurrency. but i can` t get the visit website response in method `channelRead0`

Comment: But ```ProxyRedirectHandler#channelRead0``` is sync in this way. You want to get response from ```HttpClientHandler``` and respond to client. I think the whole logic of waiting for the result and responding in ```ProxyRedirectHandler#channelRead0``` should be asynchronous.

Comment: @zysaaa yeah, i want to implement asynchronous, this is why i choose netty not springmvc to implement, how can i do?